# Delete Maximo Location Hierarchy using Automation Script

Tags: python, jython, maximo

I have a question regarding Maximo Location Hierarchy, I want to delete location hierarchy using enterprise service via CSV file, additional field is "MARKFORDELETE" has been created, in the CSV file the user need to enter "1" on the MARKFORDELETE field. And I have created the following action automation script on LOCHIERARCHY object:

```
from psdi.util.logging import MXLogger
from psdi.util.logging import MXLoggerFactory
from psdi.mbo import MboConstants
from psdi.mbo import MboSetRemote
from psdi.server import MXServer
from psdi.util import MXException

mxServer = MXServer.getMXServer();
userInfo = mbo.getUserInfo();

if launchPoint=='LOCHIERDEL2':
 locHierarchySet=mbo.getMboSet("LOCHIERARCHYDEL")
 locHierarchySet.setWhere("markfordelete = 1")
 locHierarchySet.reset()
 locHier = locHierarchySet.moveFirst()
 while locHier is not None:
  locHierarchy=locHierarchySet.getMbo(0)
  locAncestorSet=mxServer.getMboSet("LOCANCESTOR",userInfo);
  locAncestorSet.setWhere("location='"+locHierarchy.getString("LOCATION")+"' and ancestor='"+locHierarchy.getString("PARENT")+"' and systemid='"+locHierarchy.getString("SYSTEMID")+"' and siteid='"+locHierarchy.getString("SITEID")+"'")
  locAncestorSet.reset()
  locAnc = locAncestorSet.moveFirst()
  if locAncestorSet.count()==1:
   locAncestor=locAncestorSet.getMbo(0)
   locAncestor.delete(11l)
   locAncestorSet.save(11l)
  locHierarchy.delete(11l)
  locHierarchySet.save(11l)
  locHierarchySet2=mbo.getMboSet("LOCHIERARCHYDEL3")
  locHier2 = locHierarchySet2.moveFirst()
  while locHier2 is not None:
   locHierarchy2=locHierarchySet2.getMbo(0)
   locHierarchy2.delete(11l)
   locHierarchySet2.save()
   locHier2 = locHierarchySet2.moveNext()
  locHier = locHierarchySet.moveNext()
```

And the following is the CSV file:

```
EXTSYS1,LOCHIER_DEL,AddChange,EN
LOCATION,PARENT,SYSTEMID,CHILDREN,SITEID,ORGID,MARKFORDELETE
45668,XY_10603,NETWORK,0,ABC,ORG1,1
45668,XY_10604,NETWORK,0,ABC,ORG1,1
45669,XY_10606,NETWORK,0,ABC,ORG1,1
45669,XY_10607,NETWORK,0,ABC,ORG1,1
```

Create an escalation point with action using the above action script with where clause markfordelete=1. The escalation is working fine, and the records were deleted from LOCHIERARCHY table from the above CSV file, however the LOCANCESTOR table records were deleted ALL with SYSTEMID is NETWORK. and I noticed that, if the LOCHIERARCHY record is deleted, a new record will be created with parent is null.

Is there something that I have done wrong in writing the code, or have I missed out something?
Any suggestions or pointer would be great.

Answer (score 0):

That is out of box behaviour, it will create new record in lochierarchy and locancestor tables. Please look into Lochierarchy.class delete method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).